# How to set timeout?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

Want to implement timeout for RPS counter after for instance 1 second. Since here I use status change for RPS calculation, I suppose that if the state is either HIGH or LOW for more than one seconds then rps should return 0.

However, it does not work. What is the problem.

```
float rps[4]={0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00};
unsigned long int PRINT_PERIOD = 1000;
unsigned long int lastTimePrinted = 0;
int lastReedState[4];
unsigned long lastTransition[4]={0,0,0,0};
//int reedState[4];
//unsigned long now[4]={0,0,0,0};
float rps_result[4]={0,0,0,0}; 
float rps_resul[4];   
//unsigned long revolutionTime[4]={0,0,0,0};

unsigned long int LT;  // Last Time
unsigned long int PT;  // Passed Time
unsigned long int TT;  // Time



void setup(){


 Serial.begin(9600);

 DDRD &= ~_BV (7); // pinMode (7, INPUT);       // rps_1
 DDRB &= ~_BV (0); // pinMode (8, INPUT);       // rps_2
 DDRC &= ~_BV (1); // pinMode (A1, INPUT);      //  rps_3
 DDRD &= ~_BV (2); // pinMode (2, INPUT);       //  rps_4

delay(85);



}

float rps_out(int k){

    //static int lastReedState;
    //static unsigned long lastTransition;
    //static float rps_result; 
    //float rps_result;
    int reedState;
    unsigned long now;    
    unsigned long revolutionTime;

   if ( k == 0 )     reedState = (PIND & _BV (7)) == 0; // digitalRead (7);
   else if ( k==1 )  reedState = (PINB & _BV (0)) == 0; // digitalRead (8);
   else if ( k==2 )  reedState = (PINC & _BV (1)) == 0; // digitalRead (A1);
   else if ( k==3 )  reedState = (PIND & _BV (2)) == 0; // digitalRead (2);

    // On a rising transition of the reed switch:
    if (reedState == HIGH && lastReedState[k] == LOW) {                   // HIGH  LOW   measuring the low period    // LOW HIGH measuring the high period 
        // Compute time since last valid transition.
        //unsigned long now = micros();
        //unsigned long revolutionTime = now - lastTransition;       // measuring the High period
         now = micros();
         revolutionTime = now - lastTransition[k];       // measuring the High period
        // Compute the rps

        //if(revolutionTime[k] == 0 ) return 0;

        if(revolutionTime == 0 ) rps_result[k] = 0;     // avoid deviding by zero

         rps_result[k] = 1.00 / (12.00*revolutionTime) *1000000.00;  // 12 is rotary encoders resolution 

        // Remember this transition.
        lastTransition[k] = now;   

    }

    // Remember last state.
    lastReedState[k] = reedState;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   timeout 

    if(reedState == HIGH || reedState == LOW  ) {


       PT = millis();
       TT = PT - LT;       
    if( TT > 1000)  rps_result[k] = 0;

     LT = PT;

}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    if(rps_result[k] < 1) return 0.00;
    return rps_result[k]; 

}


void loop() {


   rps[0] = rps_out(0);
   rps[1] = rps_out(1);
   rps[2] = rps_out(2);
   rps[3] = rps_out(3);

    if (millis() - lastTimePrinted >= PRINT_PERIOD) {   



     Serial.print(rps[0]);
     Serial.print(',');
     Serial.print(rps[1]); 
     Serial.print(',');
     Serial.print(rps[2]);
     Serial.print(',');
     Serial.println(rps[3]);



      lastTimePrinted = millis();

     }

}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Since you need less that 1 second between changes, the minimal RPS would be 60.

So just change `if(rps_result[k] < 1) return 0.00;` to `if(rps_result[k] < 60) return 0.00;`